# My AppDelegate property is null

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, appdelegate

This may be a foolish question,but I have a variable defined as follows if my AppDelegate:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * m_sDevToken;
```

And I also have a method:

```
- (NSString *)getDeviceToken;
```

In my .m file I do the following:

```
@synthesize m_sDevToken;
```

I assign a value to m_sDevToken like this:

```
m_sDevToken = [[[[deviceToken description]
                 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<"withString:@""]
                stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""]
               stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];
```

And I have the method that return it like this:

```
- (NSString *)getDeviceToken
{
    return m_sDevToken;
}
```

I try to access it in my initial View Controller from viewDidLoad as follows:

```
BarMateAppDelegate * appDelegate = (BarMateAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSLog(@"%@", [appDelegate getDeviceToken]);
```

Now, if I log it right after I assign it, the value it correct, but in the viewDidLoad method it returns (null).

I am somewhat new to Objective-C, but similar assignments seem to work correctly, so what am I doing wrong?

Can anyone please explain to me why it would be null?

Comment: I am setting it in - (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken

Comment: Why bother with the `getDeviceToken` method? Why not simply reference the property? `NSLog(@"%@", appDelegate.m_sDevToken);`

Comment: Try setting the property in the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method instead of in the `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` method.

Comment: Ok, if I assign m_sDevToken to something in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions that seems to stick, but how will I get the value from didRegisterForRemoteNotifications in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?

Comment: LOL, Duh, my mistake.  didRegisterForRemoteNotifications happens later.  Totally makes sense now.  I guess my issues boils down to how do I get the devToken later in my app.

Answer (score 1):

define it like:

```
@property (strong) NSString * m_sDevToken;
```

otherwise it gets dealloc'd.

Comment: Most likely it should be `nonatomic` as well.

Comment: ok, i will try that, but why would readwrite, assign not be correct?

Comment: So, I changed it to @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString        * m_sDevToken; and it still appears to be null.  I also updated my post to reflect that change.

Comment: If you use (readwrite, assign), you just store the pointer, but there is nothing that keeps the object alive. stringByReplacingOccurences... returns an autoreleased object which will eventually disappear. You need to store it into a "strong" property to keep it alive. What's worse, with an "assign" property you'll keep the pointer even if the object is gone, which will lead to fun debugging when your app crashes.

Comment: By the way, `@property NSString * m_sDevToken` is automatically strong. See [Use Strong and Weak Declarations to Manage Ownership](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW30)

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple guesses of what may be wrong, but there is not enough source code to be certain.

Either way, replacing all occurrences of `m_sDevToken` with `self.m_sDevToken` should help.

```
self.m_sDevToken = [[[[deviceToken description]
                      stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<"withString:@""]
                     stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""]
                    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];
```

And

```
- (NSString *)getDeviceToken
{
    return self.m_sDevToken;
}
```

Either this will just start magically working, or you will get an error. If you get an error post that error.

Comment: No, neither of these changes are relevant to the issue. Setting the ivar directly (as the OP was doing) isn't a problem.

Comment: Yes, maddy pointed me to the issue.  I should have caught the issue, but, what I really need to do is get the dev token.  I am not sure how to have this accessible to my app since didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken happens at an indeterminate time after the app launches.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy. I was guess either `deviceToken` or he had `m_sDevToken` as a local variable which would override the iVar.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem myself based on the input from maddy. I needed to set the value elsewhere due to the delay on didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken.  Once didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken gets called I set the devToken in a settings object I have for the app.  The settings object stays around and is available later in the app.